# MSSQL, SQL flood through my web

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache

Someone was botnetting my httpd as a result my website to go down, the cpu to hit 100% and the error log to get spammed of "not enough threads left or w/e" and once I blocked all the non-cloudflare IPs, the DDoS has stopped.

He's now back though ... with sql flood. Whenever I leave my httpd open he's sql flooding my server and sqlservr process is the one which hits 100% in cpu now. I made a website copy on a sub-folder and disabled all the sql executions from the main website so everything is fine but I need a proper solution... so I must find out what sql stuff he's actually executing so I can disable or limit them.

Any ideas about how I can find all the sql executions which takes place through my web ? I remember I had a tool years ago which used to inform me about every "sql executions through web", in real time... but I forgot its name.

Any advice ?

Comment: You can run a server-side SQL trace of batch and RPC completed events, or an equivalent Extended Event trace.  The script for the SQL Trace can be created from Profiler (File-->Export-->Script trace definition).  Customize the script after saving (file path, file size, rollover files) and execute.

Comment: Also, you take a look at the sys,dm_exec_query_stats to identify how often cached queries are executed.  Order by execution_count descending.

Comment: Also, file a complaint with CloudFlare. The IP should allow them to identify the perpetrator.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a query to glean a summary of the most frequently executed queries since the instance was started.

```
SELECT TOP (100) qs.execution_count,
    SUBSTRING(qt.text,qs.statement_start_offset/2 +1, 
                 (CASE WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = -1 
                       THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), qt.text)) * 2 
                       ELSE qs.statement_end_offset end -
                            qs.statement_start_offset
                 )/2
             ) AS query_text
     , DB_NAME (qt.dbid) AS dbname
     , qs.total_rows
     , qs.total_physical_reads
     , qs.total_worker_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt 
ORDER BY 
      qs.execution_count DESC;
```

For details of individual queries, you'll need a SQL Trace or Extended Event trace of batch and RPC completed events. The script for the SQL Trace can be created from Profiler (File-->Export-->Script trace definition). Customize the script after saving (file path, file size, rollover files) and execute.